# Rotating log files using logrotate command

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I'm very new to apache. We wish to rotate the log files in daily basis. We installed the apache2 using :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

in Ubuntu. Are there any ways to do it using `logrotate` ?

Answer (score 2):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048/best-way-to-rotate-apache-log-files

In particular, read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/rotatelogs.html

But yes, it shouldn't be at all difficult to use `logrotate` to rotate your apache log files.

Your `httpd.conf` and associated files will specify the locations of the log files, you can then use this information to configure logrotate

Don't forget to get Apache to restart logging, e.g. use a graceful restart (`apachectl graceful` or equivalent)